# Usercontrol not posting back in IE

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, umbraco

I am using Umbraco CMS to create a new site. I have added a .NET user control for the contact form. However, when clicking submit the page doesn't postback in IE, but it is working in FF.

I can't think of why this is the case. I've tried to take all validation controls off and the problem remains.

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Cam you point us to the html source ouput?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure IE is not throwing Javascript errors that would prevent a postback.

Comment: Yeah sorry I should have mentioned that in the Question. It DOES NOT throw any javascript errors.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Ryan, I doubt this is an Umbraco specific problem. But have you debugged the usercontrol and stepped through the code to see what is happening?

I recommend you attach to process and see what exactly is going on.

Warren :)

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not help, but i had a similar issue recently.  Turned out I had used an ImageButton, and the image was not referenced correctly. When clicking the text displayed in FF it worked fine, but IE choked.

So make sure if its an ImageButton that the image path is correct.